# c# equality check for class containing reference type properties

Tags: c#, equality, reference-type

If we have a class that contains properties/fields of other reference types, how would a proper and elegant equality check be performed?

For example, `MainClass` contains properties of `SubClassA` and `SubClassB`. We can assume that all of these classes override `object.Equals` with the same implementation, what would that be?

I came up with the following which doesn't look very nice. My logic is as follows:

1. We cannot use `Equals` directly on the reference types because they can be null, so we first check if only one of them is null, which leads to inequality.
2. Then, if both have a value, make sure the value is equal.
3. We can omit the check that they are both null as it leads to equality.

   ```
   class MainClass {
       SubClassA A {get; set;}
       SubClassB B {get; set;}
       int someint {get; set;}

       public override bool Equals(object obj) {
           MainClass other = obj as MainClass;
           if (other is null)
               return false;

           // First check if only one of the As is null.
           if (A is null ^ other.A is null) {
               return false;
           }
           // Then check if both have a value that the value is equal.
           else if (A != null && other.A != null && !A.Equals(other.A)) {
               return false;
           }
           // Case where As are both null is omitted as it leads to equality.

           // Same principle here and for any other reference types...
           if (B is null ^ other.B is null) {
               return false;
           }
           else if (B != null && other.B != null && !B.Equals(other.B)) {
               return false;
           }

           // Value types can go down here.
           return someint.Equals(other.someint);
       }
   }

   class SubClassA {
       // some properties
   }

   class SubClassB {
       // some properties
   }
   ```

Comment: Don't just implement an `Equals()` override. Implement the [equals operator `==`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type#class-example) and `!=` too.
`SubClassA.Equals()` should do a `null` check for `other`. `SubClassA.operator ==` should do a `null` check for the left side (that's possible because it's `static`). Now you can reduce the `if/else if` for each reference type property to: `if (A != other.A) return false;` or even better just chain multiple of them with `&&`.

Comment: Implementing equality is a little tricky to do correctly and involves the `IEquatable` interface, overriding `Equals(object)`, implementing `==` and `!=`, as well as overriding `GetGashCode()`. It's lots of annoying boilerplate code. But if you use `record`s instead of `class`es the compiler will implement it all for you. Have you considered that?

Comment: The first comment was something I thought would be the solution, i.e. the null checks will be able to be avoided somehow. As for using records, it is probably possible for most cases where intances don't have an id field, which should not be accounted for in the equality check. Sadly, I am tied to C# 7.2 right now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel. .NET has an [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1.default?view=net-8.0) property that can handle most of equality comparison situations (including yours). Read the remark section for more details.

```
EqualityComparer<SubClassA>.Default.Equals(A, other.A);
```

Note, please read this article: [System.Object.Equals method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-object-equals) if you want to override `Equals`. In summary, you'd better override the `GetHashCode` method and implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface too.

Comment: The docs state that ```EqualityComparer<T>.Default``` will use the ```IEquatable<T>``` equality check if possible, then ```Object.Equals```. Doesn't that mean in my case that I will have to implement ```IEquatable<T>``` for all subclasses first in order to be able to use it in ```MainClass```?

Comment: That means if `IEquatable<T>` is not implemented, it will use `Object.Equals`.

Answer (score 0):

If the class/subclass is made up of only POCO or serializable objects, then serialize and compare the strings.
Any other solution would require you to override Equals() and GetHashCode(). It is not worth the pain. Rather, create a specific method (say, "ValueEquals()") that compares specific members of the two objects.